# How can i change date format in vue js template

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, react-native, vue.js

This is the format i got

```
2019-01-08T11:11:00.000Z
```

This is the format i want

```
2019-01-08
```

How can i format date like that?

Note: I don't want moment package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Date` constructor to create the new date object from your date string. Then you can create the date in any custom format using this object. See the code below.

```js
const input = "2019-01-08T11:11:00.000Z";

const dateObj = new Date(input);

const year = dateObj.getFullYear();
const month = (dateObj.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
const date = dateObj.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');

const result = `${year}-${month}-${date}`;

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the native Date objects in JavaScript

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

```js
const result = input.toLocaleDateString('de-DE').split('.').reverse().join('-')
```